# Can not get url parameters in facebook canvas application?

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing a facebook canvas application
When i click links it has to print testid and view variables which is get from url according to the code on index.php

https://apps.facebook.com/gayriciddi/

index.php:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
include ('db_fns.php');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

print_r($fbme);
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

//records users to database
create_user($fbme, $access_token); 

$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'home' : $_GET['view'];

$controller = 'page';

echo '<br />'.$view;

$testid = $_REQUEST['testid'];

echo '<br />'.$testid.'<br />';

switch($view){

    case 'home':
        $testler = select_tests();   
    break;

    case 'acilis':

    break;

    case 'sayfa':

    break;

    case 'kapanis':

    break;
}

//includes $view.php  $view is home, acilis, sayfa or kapanis
include(WEBSITE_ROOT.'/views/'.$controller.'.php');
?>
```

home.php:

```
    <table width="601" border="0">
 <?php foreach($testler as $key => $test){?>
  <tr>
    <td width="53">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="420"><a href="<?=FB_BASE_URL?>index.php?view=acilis&testid=<?=$test['id']?>" target="_top"><?php echo $test['ad'];?></a></td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>
```

All variables are defined if you look at link i have gave on top. When i click links it has to print testid and view variables which is get from url according to the code on index.php

```
$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'home' : $_GET['view'];

$controller = 'page';

echo '<br />'.$view;

$testid = $_REQUEST['testid'];
```

But it doesn't. Maybe it has very simple solution but i couldn't find it.

On the other hand when i do the same thing in original url (http://www.olmasigereken.com/gayriciddi/) it prints $view and $testid as expected.

Comment: GET parameters are not passed into the iframe where your app is called by Facebook. Use the `app_data` parameter if you need to pass values from the Facebook URL to your iframed app.

Comment: @CBroe Can you provide a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/